# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Message.getHeaders

Tags: maven, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm trying to connect to a CMIS server with Apache Chemistry,
when it is configured with an AtomPumb url it works ok, but when I swith to webservices and when it tries to create a session it throws this error:

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Message.getHeaders()
    Lcom/sun/xml/internal/ws/api/message/HeaderList;
```

these are the dependencies in my POM:

```
    <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-commons-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-workbench</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

what is the problem? that class is in the rt.jar, that is in the jre lib folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with OpenCMIS 0.13.0 on Java 8. See 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-917. This has been fixed in OpenCMIS 0.14.0.

**Avoid the CMIS Web Services binding! The other CMIS bindings are significantly faster!**

Comment: [The Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS page](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) only mentions versions up to 0.13.0 - is the page out of date, or is a release overdue? ;-)

Comment: yes, removing that class make it work. hope chemistry releases 0.14.0 soon and with that correction.

Comment: and I have to use Webservices binding instead of Apompub b'cos Chemistry is not founding a folder by path when it has special characters: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36581970/how-to-set-charset-in-apache-chemistry-cmis-api)

Comment: Thank you for ending an 1hr + of going around in circles.